# Python connecting divided contours on image

Tags: python, image, algorithm, opencv, contour

[HERE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S1lTI.png) is the 6 contours in different color.

I want to connecting two biggest part.
In the image green and blue parts.

Is there any algorithms or library to handle this problem??

Comment: You mat try morphology operations such as `cv::dilate`

Comment: @ZdaR Yes It works! thank you so much.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using the dilate function mentioned earlier in addition to using the closing operations will most likely yield the best results.

```
import cv2 
import numpy as np

image = cv2.imread("images/S1lTI.png")

cv2.imshow('Original', image)
cv2.waitKey(0)

kernel = np.ones((5,5), np.uint8)

dilation = cv2.dilate(image, kernel, iterations = 3)
cv2.imshow('Dilation', dilation)
cv2.waitKey(0)

closing = cv2.morphologyEx(dilation, cv2.MORPH_CLOSE, kernel)
cv2.imshow('Closing', closing)
cv2.waitKey(0)
```